Python threads behaviour on ctrl+c during join
I'm struggling to understand what happens to other threads when ctrl+c interrupts the main thread while it's waiting for the other thread to finish.
Here's a small snippet of code to illustrate an example.
import time, threading

def worker():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Thread finished")

t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
t.start()
try:
    t.join()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Interrupted")

With this code, if I hit ctrl+c before the 5s are up, I expect the main thread to have a KeyboardInterrupt raised within the join, then it would get caught by the except block, printing "Interrupted".
Then the main thread would reach the end of its code and exit, but python should not shut down yet until the thread completes, since it's not a daemon thread. The thread should then print "Thread finished", and only then the python process should exit.
This is in line with my observations using python 3.6 and 3.7, however when I try this on Linux with python 3.10.12, 3.11.3, 3.12.0, and 3.12.3, it prints "Interrupted" and the process immediately exits.
What seems even stranger to me is that if I replace the t.join() with a time.sleep(100000) then it does wait for the thread to finish before exiting... It seems as if the thread is being abruptly aborted if the ctrl+c happens during the join, but not otherwise...
I couldn't find any explanation for this in the docs. The only relevant information I found was this, which seems to me like the newer python versions are misbehaving.

The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are left.

Is this actually just a bug or is there a real explanation that I don't know as to why it behaves this way? If so, is there any way to have the documented behaviour in 3.12?
UPDATE: On windows, as Booboo pointed out, the KeyboardInterrupt will not even be raised until the .join() is done.

I think this bug is what causes this behaviour. https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/90882

The KeyBoardInterrupt exception will not be raised in the main thread while it is blocking on the call to join while the child thread continues to run unaffected by the interrupt, which only occurs within the main thread. So you need two changes:

Make the thread a daemon thread so that when you do catch the exception you can terminate and the child thread will automatically terminate along with it.
Specify a short timeout value for the call to join in a loop as follows:

import time, threading

def worker():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Thread finished")

t = threading.Thread(target=worker, daemon=True)
t.start()

try:
    while t.is_alive():
        t.join(.1)
except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
    print('Interrupted')

Update
I am running Python 3.12.2 on both Windows and Linux.
On Linux if I have t.join() or t.join(.1) in a loop as in the above code, then when Ctrl-C is entered the main thread prints 'Interrupted' and the child thread is immediately terminated. However, if I instead execute the following code where I am no longer doing any call to 'join', then the child thread completes normally and prints out 'Thread finished'. So it seems that the child thread is terminated if the main thread is executing a call to join on the child thread when the Ctrl-C is entered:
import time, threading

def worker():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Thread finished")

done_event = threading.Event()
t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
t.start()

try:
    while t.is_alive():
        time.sleep(.1)
except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
    print('Interrupted')

Prints:
^CInterrupted
Thread finished


As I said, "when I try this [...] it prints "Interrupted" and the process immediately exits". Clearly the KeyboardInterrupt is being raised while blocking on the join

Also making it a daemon will make it so that when the main thread finishes the worker does too, but I'm asking the other way. I expect that (when it's not a daemon) the worker should NOT terminate until it finished, even if there's a KeyboardInterrupt, but in 3.11/3.12 it is aborting early

Regarding combining is_alive() with join(timeout), the same behaviour occurs. It still exits early. I believe the culprit is the bug that I commented on the question... join has a try/except that calls self._stop, causing keyboard interrupts during join to set the state of the thread as stopped

Okay, so let's not make the child thread a daemon thread. I am running Python 3.12.2 under Windows. When Ctrl-C is entered, the child thread continues to run because the exception is not raised in child threads. So even though the main thread terminates the child thread will continue to run and eventually print its finished message. I also tried this under Linux and I see the same behavior. So I cannot duplicate what you say is occurring.

That's odd... I tried on multiple machines (Ubuntu, arch) and they all ended immediately

In windows you are correct about not raising until join is done. This is not true for linux though. What python version did you use to reproduce this in linux? I just checked with 3.12.3 and again, it aborts early, interrupting the thread

See my update above.
